# What syntax rules explain how C++ compilers process the const keyword in variable declarations

Tags: c++, syntax, constants

```
char * const a;
const char * a;
```

One is a constant pointer to a char. The other is a pointer to a char const.

I think there is a specific way. Something like order of execution. I think there should be brackets around or something.

Can anyone explain to me why the pointer is const on one and not the other?

```
char * const a, for example.
```

Does that become `(char *) const a`

Or

`const char * a`

Is it `(const (char *)) a`

In [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const) I got a bunch of explanations that do not seem to make sense.

One explanation is to read it backward.

Another explanation is to split the * and see if the const is on the right or left.

Then there is another bizare theory of doing it clockwise

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

The rules do not seem like the real actual formal rule. I am not even sure if the rule holds for even more complex types. Not to mention the rules only work in english.

Okay, what's the actual formal rule here and what's the reference?

I think there has to be a simpler rule on why this is so.

For example, does the word const apply to the left or right? Can we put brackets like I suggest?

Comment: if you write it `char const *a` it becomes clearer. `const` qualifier refers to its left operand.

Comment: what? what "order of execution"? why would you care how it is compiled? this makes no sense at all.

Comment: const qualifier refers to its left operand. Okay, that's an info. That's the sort of thing I want to know.

Comment: -1 Your question needs a rework (or a delete): What is/was/will be your actual problem?

Comment: I want to understand the actual formal rule on complex type declaration. The supposedly duplicate questions give informal rules, like read it backwards. But reading it backwards would only work in English. I want the formal rules.

Comment: -(-1) sorry I did not read carefully enough, but it's rather difficult to keep track of a changing question.

Comment: Check Matt's answer. That's on the right direction.

Comment: It's not duplicate. The question ask for the grammar rule in general. Not a few common pointer case.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are in the C++ standard. You can download free drafts from links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479).

Appendices A.6 and A.7 have the full grammar specification. The description of declarators is in chapter `[dcl]`. See section `[dcl.ptr]` in particular, e.g. #1:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `*` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *cv-qualifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> `D1`
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`,” then the type of the identifier of `D` is “*derived-declarator-type-list cv-qualifier-seq* pointer to `T`.” The *cv-qualifiers* apply to the pointer and not to the object pointed to. Similarly, the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* (7.6.1) appertains to the pointer and not to the object pointed to.

The rest of that section contains a bunch of clarifying examples.

Comment: This seems to be the one making most sense. Can you elaborate with samples? What is attribute-sepcifier-seq? for example?

Comment: Read the standard draft first and come back if you have any more specific questions

Comment: +1 this teaser should be enough BTW: the list of free drafts starts here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/2932052

Comment: The standard draft is freakin big. This is a simple question.

Comment: @JimThio you're not happy with the simple answers ...  Paul Evans answered perfectly and you go "why? any reference?" . The C++ standard is the reference. What more do you want?

Comment: Somewhere in the middle. Not a whole freakin draft. Not an unclear answer.

Comment: It's clear to me. I also indicated in my which sections of the standard you should look at , and even quoted it for you.  If there is anything you still don't understand then you need to ask a more specific question. For example, post a line of code you can't understand and say exactly what you don't get about it.  It's no coincidence your question is sitting at -4 .

Answer (score 1):

The rule is *very* simple, if the `const` is on the *right-hand-side* of the `*`: it's the pointer that's `const`.  If the `const` is on the *left-hand-side* of the `*` then the object that's being pointed to is `const`.

Comment: And why is that? Any reference?

Comment: @JimThio the C++ standard (any version) is your best ref

Comment: Is that the real rule or just an symptom of the real rule?

Comment: is that a real question or just a symptom of some doubt?

Comment: Matt's answer is closer to truth. I just need a little elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

A [**pragmatic online reference**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) of the syntax for const pointer declarations saves you downloading some 1400 pages of a [draft version of any C++ Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/2932052) (a SO-community-maintained list).

The formal grammar is covered in **Appendix A** of the book **The C++ Programming Language** by **Bjarne Stroustrup** [ISBN 0-321-563840](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0321563840) (every former edition will do, too). In chapter 5.4.1 (of the 3rd edition), Bjarne Stroustrup describes the reason behind this syntax diversity as follows:

> The declarator operator that makes a pointer constant is `*const`. There is no `const*` declarator operator, so a `const` appearing before the `*` is taken to be part of the base type.

### Ask your C++ compiler!

It's most likely that compiler implementers don't like<sup>[1]</sup> this "feature": if you try the following declaration,

```
const char const * const a;
```

you'll see that there are special rules implemented in your C++ compiler, and it will probably tell you about it. The GNU GCC compiler for example states

> error: duplicate 'const'

---

<sup>[1]</sup> ...but this anger seems negligible compared with that created by [unsigned long literals...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why? I added a good reference. The drafts are about 1400 pages, nobody want's to download these.

Comment: Let me check the reference again.

Comment: There are also books about C++ with a syntax appendix. Maybe I'll add this too.